# Finding mode and frequency of mode without sorting in Java

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops, frequency, mode

I'm new to Java, and was given a question to solve as a weekend project. I ran into some troubles, and would like your help. Please understand I am a beginner. If I'm wrong somewhere, please explain it to me. I hope to be a good programmer too some day.

I did a through search, and found answers with things like "heatmaps" or "arraylists", something I probably won't be allowed to use since I haven't learned it yet.

Ok, so the question given to me was:

> Find:  1) Mode, the most frequently occurring marks in the class. If 2 or more marks occur equally frequently, then the highest of these marks is the mode.
>
> 2) Mode Frequency: Frequency of mode.
>
> It is assumed that the class has 10 students and marks are between 0 to 100.You are not allowed to sort the marks.

This is my code for finding the mode:

```
void mode()
{
    int c[]=new int[10];
    int arr[]=new int[10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {   
        for (int j=i+1;j<10;j++)
        {
            for (int k=0;k<10;k++)
            {
                if (marks[i]!=arr[k])
                {               
                    if (marks[i]==marks[j])
                    {
                        c[i]++;
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }
            arr[i]=marks[i];
        }
    }
    for (int k=0;k<10;k++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(c[k]);
    }
}
```

Where marks[] is the int array where I take the input, c[] is to count the number of times the number is occurring, and arr[] is an array to cross check if the number has previously occurred or not.

Let's assume the 10 numbers inputted are 99, 95, 97, 92, 80, 95, 73, 80, 95, 80. As you can see 95 and 80 occur three times.

So my c[] should have {0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, but when I run it, it comes as {0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, which means my program isn't cross checking with arr[].

I think I've made a mess using three for-loops. I can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: I'd like to ask why sorting is not allowed ? what is the book or teacher trying to test here ?

Comment: Sorting isn't necessary. See answer by @vandale.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to have an array of length 101 initialized to zero. This array would represent the number of times a specific mark had occurred. each time you encounter a specific mark you increment the count. Then to find the mode, you simple find the index with the highest count.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Loader
{

    // We suppose that the parameter is not null
    public static void mode_frequency(long collection[])
    {
        long frequencies[] = new long[collection.length];
        for (int i = 0, l = collection.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < l; j++)
            {
                if (collection[i] == collection[j])
                {
                    ++frequencies[i];
                }
            }
        }

        // With your example {99, 95, 97, 92, 80, 95, 73, 80, 95, 80}
        // You should have somthing like {1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1}
        //
        // As you can see, you just have to find the MAX frequency and then, print corresponding values from initial array
        long frequency = 0;
        for (int i = 0, l = frequencies.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (frequency < frequencies[i])
            {
                frequency = frequencies[i];
            }
        }
        // Print each mode
        for (int i = 0, l = collection.length; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (frequencies[i] == frequency)
            {
                System.out.println(collection[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mode_frequency(new long[]
        {
            99,
            95,
            97,
            92,
            80,
            95,
            73,
            80,
            95,
            80
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use an algorithm in which you use secondary arrays to accumulate the counts for individual marks, and then search through those secondary arrays for the mark with the highest frequency with largest value.  Consider:

```
package com.example.mode;

public class Mode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] marks = { 99, 95, 97, 92, 80, 95, 73, 80, 95, 80};


        //One algorithm .. insert marks and add occurances, keeping in order

        int[] unique  = new int[marks.length];
        int[] count = new int[marks.length];
        int maxUnique = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < marks.length ; i++) {
            int loc = -1;
            for (int j=0; j < maxUnique; j++) {
                if (marks[i] == unique[j]) {
                    loc = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (loc == -1) {
                loc = maxUnique;
                unique[loc] = marks[i];
                count[loc] = 0;
                maxUnique++;
            }
            count[loc] = count[loc]+1;
        }
        int maxValue = unique[0];
        int maxCount = count[0];
        for (int j=1; j < maxUnique; j++) {
            if (count[j] > maxCount || (count[j] == maxCount && maxValue < unique[j]) ) {
                maxValue = unique[j];
                maxCount = count[j];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Mode = " + maxValue + ", frequency = " + maxCount);

    }

}
```